# Taxes for resident alien investing in mutual funds and money market funds?

Tags: united-states, taxes, mutual-funds

As a resident alien working in the US, what kinds of taxes will I be liable for when investing in mutual funds and money market funds?

Some funds are federal, state, or municipal tax-exempt, will that apply to me?

Thanks!

Comment: not sure if the question is about your "resident alien" status or mutual fund exemptions?

Comment: Maybe both? i.e. What are the different tax considerations if you are a resident alien, instead of a citizen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resident Alien is liable for the same taxes as a citizen. Citizenship has nothing to do with taxes.